# Installing Demo Datasets for QGIS

Tags: qgis, data, installation

I installed QGIS without selecting the demo datasets. Now I realise that was a mistake.

Is there a way to install these after QGIS installation or do I have to uninstall completely and re-install?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply download the sample data from http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/data/qgis_sample_data.zip